# My counter is reset after exiting the loop

Tags: arrays, node.js, count

My counter `count` resets after each time the second `forEach` loop exits but it is not meant to be reset, as when I console log inside the second loop the numbers are correct but with no luck.

```
    let arr = [];
    var count;
    result.forEach(server => {
      count = 0;
      sql.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE server='${server.server}';`, async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        results.forEach(user => {
          if(user.key_deactivated == 'false') {
            count++;
          }
        });
        console.log(count);
      });
      arr.push({
        server: server.server,
        name: server.name,
        plan_id: server.plan_id,
        mb_stripe: server.mb_stripe,
        description: server.description,
        key_stock: server.key_stock,
        channel: server.channel,
        active: count
      });
    });
        res.render('pages/administrator', {result: result, user: req.user, arr: arr});
```

Comment: then why have you included `count = 0` in the outer loop ? just put it out.

Comment: it resets on every server but when pushing to the array it pushes as 0 and not the original number that was logged out and if you look closely the arr.push is before the end of the loop so it should push the correct information

Answer (score 1):

you are using callback function and callback function is part of asynchronous behavior. means js pushes it to a callback queue to execute it later. so the count value is being accessed before the callback can change it.

```js
  let arr = [];
    var count;
    result.forEach(server => {
      count = 0;
      sql.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE server='${server.server}';`, async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        results.forEach(user => {
          if(user.key_deactivated == 'false') {
            count++;
          }
        });
        console.log(count);
           arr.push({
            server: server.server,
            name: server.name,
            plan_id: server.plan_id,
            mb_stripe: server.mb_stripe,
            description: server.description,
            key_stock: server.key_stock,
            channel: server.channel,
            active: count
         });

         res.render('pages/administrator', {result: result, user: req.user, arr: arr});
      });
    });
```

for more information on callback check this out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: Sorry forgot to add render line to the callback.. now it should work as expected

Comment: That would render multiple times wouldn't it? it only needs to render once though

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

> "Abandon all hope, ye who enter here."

Dante Alighieri

The less poetic description of your issue is that you are using callbacks and expect them to be executed before the code you see after them. But it is not how they work. Let me explain what your code does:

It iterates result and for each instance it sets `count` to 0 and asynchronously waits for a query to execute and while waiting for the query to execute, without actually waiting it to be executed it pushes objects (containing `count`) to `arr`. But `count` is not yet refreshed yet, the queries are still being executed. Just put this code

```
  arr.push({
    server: server.server,
    name: server.name,
    plan_id: server.plan_id,
    mb_stripe: server.mb_stripe,
    description: server.description,
    key_stock: server.key_stock,
    channel: server.channel,
    active: count
  });
```

just after your `console.log`.